# Java, JavaFX, Abakus: How to keep ghost image on rod of Abakus and within window during dragging?

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

This shows my problem, the ball should stay on the rod (original y position) during dragging, but it does not.

[image: ball dragged of the rod]

This is the relevant code:

```
    protected void makeImageDragNDrop(ImageView imageView)
    {
      imageView.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
         if (imageView.getId().contains(LEER))
         {
            event.consume();
            return;
         }
         Dragboard dragboard = imageView.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
         ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
         ArrayList<ImageView> imageViewList = findViewList(imageView,
               (HBox) imageView.getParent());
         Image ghostImage = createGhostImage(imageViewList);
         Label ghostLabel = new Label("",new ImageView(ghostImage));
         dragboard.setDragView(ghostImage);
         ghostLabel.setOnMouseEntered(this::ballOnTheRod);
         ghostLabel.setOnMousePressed(this::keepBallOnTheRod);
         dragboard.setDragViewOffsetY(25.0);
         dragboard.setDragViewOffsetX(25.0);
         clipboardContent.put(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT, uuid.toString());
         dragboard.setContent(clipboardContent);
         this.currentStartDragList = imageViewList;
         event.consume();
      });

      imageView.setOnDragOver(event -> {
         Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
         String origin = (String) dragboard.getContent(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT);
         UUID originUUID = UUID.fromString(origin);
         if (uuid.compareTo(originUUID) == 0) // identisch
         {
            if (imageView.getId().contains(VOLL))
            {
               event.consume();
               return;
            }
            if (this.currentStartDragList.size() > 0)
            {
               event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
            }
         }
         event.consume();
      });

      imageView.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
         if (imageView.getId().contains(VOLL))
         {
            event.consume();
            return;
         }
         if (this.currentStartDragList.size() > 0)
         {
            ImageView bestView = findLocation((HBox) imageView.getParent());
            setImages(imageView.getParent(), bestView);
            event.setDropCompleted(true);
         }
         event.consume();
      });

      imageView.setOnDragDone(event -> {

         if (event.getTransferMode() == null)
         {
            // Kugel falsch fallen gelassen
            for (ImageView currentStartDragView : this.currentStartDragList)
            {
               currentStartDragView.setImage(new Image(
                     Images.class.getResourceAsStream(KUGEL_FARBE_PNG)));
               currentStartDragView
                     .setId(currentStartDragView.getId().replace(LEER, VOLL));
            }
            if (this.kugelWasOnTheLeft)
            {
               this.subtract(this.currentStartDragList.size());
            }
            else
            {
               this.add(this.currentStartDragList.size());
            }
            this.currentStartDragList = new ArrayList<>();
         }
      });
    }
   
    private void ballOnTheRod(MouseEvent event)
    {
       this.yValue = ((Label)event.getSource()).getTranslateY();
    }
   
    private void keepBallOnTheRod(MouseEvent event)
    {
       ((Label)event.getSource()).setTranslateY(yValue);
    }

    private Image createGhostImage(ArrayList<ImageView> imageViewList)
    {
       HBox horizontal = new HBox();
       for (@SuppressWarnings("unused")
       ImageView view : imageViewList)
       {
          // view wird nicht gebraucht
          horizontal.getChildren().add(new ImageView(
                new Image(Images.class.getResourceAsStream(KUGEL_FARBE_PNG))));
       }
       return horizontal.snapshot(null, null);
    }
```

I tried putting ghostimage in an ImageView and restrict the ImageView. Then I tried putting the ghostimage in a Label and restrict the Label. But unfortunately I can still drag the ghostimage everywhere. Even of the window and then the ball is lost.

I googled an found other questions but they did not have any answers. Does that mean it is impossible to keep dragged ghostimage on a certain y-position? It would be worth knowing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't use a `DragView` for this.  The `DragView` will follow the mouse position, which can be moved in both x and y directions.  Instead you want to [drag a standard node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312734/how-to-make-a-draggable-node-in-javafx-2-0), but only update the x value when dragged, not the y value.  I'm not sure you would even want a ghost image or drag and drop for this.  Normally you can slide multiple balls at a time in an abacus I think, not just one (not that I have used an abacus in a long time), I assume your code does this?

Comment: As an aside, JDK 22 (released in about a week) adds [unamed variables](https://openjdk.org/jeps/456), which is a nicer way to handle unused variables than `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`.

Comment: @jewelsea Thank you for the suggestion to use "drag a standard node". I did not knew there is a second kind of dragging. Yes multiple balls can be dragged at once.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47338719/2423906) can help.